# Cannot immediately destroy modal elements created with Foundation for Apps

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm using the ModalFactory included with [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/angular-modules) to programmatically create modals which works fine, but my use case requires me to force a redraw of the modal each time it's called. However, when trying to destroy modals, I have found that the source for ModalFactory.destroy includes a 3 second timeout before it destroys the element which seems to be causing all sorts of issues.

I am wondering if there is a workaround for immediately destroying the element.

```
// ModalFactory.destroy source:      
function destroy() {
    self.deactivate();
    setTimeout(function() {
      scope.$destroy();
      element.remove();
      destroyed = true;
    }, 3000);
    foundationApi.unsubscribe(id);
}
```

Comment: you need to change `setTimeout` to `$timeout` to ensure the digest cycle will run

Comment: @pankajparkar: Thank you, you were spot on. I was hoping to workaround without modifying the source but it seems as your modification is the most complete fix to the issue. Guess I'll submit a PR to zurb for this but to anyone dealing with this in the mean time, switching setTimeout(fn(){},3000) to $timeout(fn(){},0,false) in the destroy function as Pankaj suggests does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `setTimeout` function which is JavaScript native function, by running which your `digest` cycle will not fire the digest cycle. Resultant will be binding will not work if you have changed any `scope` level object. For avoiding such problem angular has provided `$timeout` service which work as that of same as `setTimeout` only does run digest cycle after callback time completed.

```
// ModalFactory.destroy source:      
function destroy() {
    self.deactivate();
    $timeout(function() {
      scope.$destroy();
      element.remove();
      destroyed = true;
    }, 3000);
    foundationApi.unsubscribe(id);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when running inside angular's digest cycle, the 3 second timeout does not appear to be necessary. Using `$timeout(fun...},0,false)` avoids weird timing issues created by the needless wait. It's also probably worth noting is that this ModalFactory function resides in `/foundation-apps/js/angular/components/modal/modal.js`

Comment: By writing false in $timeout function means it will not run digest cycle